# Error in pdfkit in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have done

```
gem install pdfkit
gem install wkhtmltopdf
```

in application.rb 
added

```
config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware", :print_media_type => true
```

when i go to the link to pdf with .pdf extension

it shows Error as follows

```
No wkhtmltopdf executable found at bundler: command not found: which
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
>> Please install wkhtmltopdf -https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/wiki/Installing WKHTMLTOPD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One guess is that you're using Windows, but the library expects the `which` command, that is available on systems like OS X and Linux, but not on Windows.

If you are using Windows, you might have better success running Rails inside [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).